# How do you change from Landscape to Portrait Layout in python ReportLab?

Tags: python, reportlab

I have a newbie question (should be simple to answer) that has been bugging me for the past day or so and after pouring over all online posts related to reportlab still can't be figured out.  All I am trying to do is switch from landscape to portrait orientation in the same document.  This will allow me to create a table of features (including links to the pictures of these within the table) and then put in the pictures so they can be linked to.

Here is the code I have come up with so far to facilitate what should be a straight forward process:

```
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_RIGHT, TA_CENTER, TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image, Frame,
                   Table, TableStyle, NextPageTemplate, PageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Flowable, PageBreak
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import glob, os
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4

doc = BaseDocTemplate("M:\GIS Mapping Services\Promotional\Automated Reports\PDF_ReportLab\NextPageExample.pdf",showBoundary=1,pagesize=landscape(letter))
elements = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='normal', fontSize=6, leading = 7, alignment=TA_LEFT))

ptemplate = PageTemplate(id='portrait', pagesize=portrait(letter))
elements.append(Paragraph("Table is here.",styles["normal"]))
elements.append(NextPageTemplate('portrait'))
elements.append(PageBreak())
elements.append(Paragraph("Pictures are to be placed here.",styles["normal"]))

doc.build(elements)
del elements
```

If you have any tips or would like to help me out with this can you please be specific and show me exactly what I am doing wrong or include a working example that goes from start to finish without any coding missing.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Winn

Comment: I recall that this is possible because I think I did it once, but be warned that switching page size in a document can be buggy. I abandoned this because even once I got it to "work" I still had trouble printing and reliably displaying in all PDF readers. Not sure if this is a matter of the way ReportLab does things or inherent to PDF.

Comment: But I'm not trying to change page size, just orientation.  I would like to keep all pages at a standard letter size.  -Winn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a hack, based on the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882636/how-to-create-a-pdf-document-with-differing-page-sizes-in-reportlab-python).

```
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_RIGHT, TA_CENTER, TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image, Frame,Table, TableStyle, NextPageTemplate, PageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Flowable, PageBreak
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import glob, os
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4

def make_portrait(canvas,doc):
    canvas.setPageSize(letter)

def make_landscape(canvas,doc):
    canvas.setPageSize(landscape(letter))

doc = BaseDocTemplate("NextPageExample.pdf",showBoundary=1)
elements = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='normal', fontSize=6, leading = 7, alignment=TA_LEFT))


frame1 = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.height-5*inch,
                doc.width, 5*inch,
                leftPadding = 0, rightPadding = 0,
                topPadding = 0, bottomPadding = 0,
                id='frame1')

ptemplate = PageTemplate(id='portrait',frames =[frame1], onPage=make_portrait)
ltemplate = PageTemplate(id='landscape',frames =[frame1], onPage=make_landscape)
doc.addPageTemplates([ptemplate, ltemplate])
elements.append(Paragraph("Table is here.",styles["normal"]))
elements.append(NextPageTemplate('landscape'))
elements.append(PageBreak())
elements.append(Paragraph("Pictures are to be placed here.",styles["normal"]))

doc.build(elements)
del elements
```

When working with platypus, the easiest way I've found to manipulate the canvas is via the onPage setting of a PageTemplate that lets you implement the non-flowing part of the text. Here, before anything is drawn on either the landscape or portrait template, the canvas is re-sized to the desired size.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for the help.  With a little tweaking I was able to get the layout I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, I just spent a few weeks on a reportlab project at work and I know how obtuse the documentation can be. Stackoverflow got answers pretty quickly, so feel free to post more questions. Also, if my answer worked for you, click on the check next to my answer to accept it. This not only gives me credit, but also makes people happier to answer questions for you when they know you accept them.

Comment: Hahaha, looks like I did in fact previously answer this question, but without Platypus.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I was a little to quick to say this problem is solved.  For the life of me I still can't get what I am trying to accomplish.  The code above allows going from portrait to landscape orientation.  However, I am really trying to start with a landscape orientation and move to a portrait orientation.  For some reason, setting the pagesize to landscape(letter) still creates a portrait orientation.

Comment: Just change the order of the page templates. By putting ptemplate first, that is the default template. Then calling `elements.append(NextPageTemplate('landscape'))` makes the next page landscape. To change the order, change the line
`doc.addPageTemplates([ptemplate, ltemplate])`
to `doc.addPageTemplates([ltemplate, ptemplate])` and then instead of calling `elements.append(NextPageTemplate('landscape'))` call `elements.append(NextPageTemplate('portrait'))`

Comment: Where are you changing the pagesize that isn't working? The pagesize in BaseDocTemplate doesn't do anything, as the content is placed on the page templates, which have their own pagesizes. I've removed the BaseDocTemplate pagesize setting, as this is over-ridden by the size of the templates

Comment: Brilliant.  Ok, works the way I was hoping now.  Thanks again.  I guess it didn't really occur to me that the order of adding the page templates actually affected which one the document starts out with.  And yeah, knowing that setting the page size when creating the BaseDocTemplate is pointless helps a lot too.  Btw, I tried giving you credit for the answer but it said I need a reputation of 15 or more.  Any idea how to get that?

Comment: Glad it ended up working out. Reputation is earned by asking good questions and giving good answers. You have 10(+1 for starting) for asking this question and getting 2 votes. You do need 15 rep to vote my answer up, but to click the check mark left of my answer and accept it doesn't take any rep. Also, it will give you 2 rep!

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the above further. There is no need for the two additional functions to set the rotated canvas:

```
    p_frame = Frame(0.5 * inch, 0.5 * inch, 7.5 * inch, 10 * inch,
                   leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0,
                   topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0,
                   id='portrait_frame')

    l_frame = Frame(0.5 * inch, 0.5 * inch, 10 * inch, 7.5 * inch,
                    leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0,
                    topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0,
                    id='landscape_frame')

    portrait_tmpl = PageTemplate(id='portrait_tmpl', frames=[p_frame], pagesize=letter)
    landscape_tmpl = PageTemplate(id='landscape_tmpl', frames=[l_frame], pagesize=landscape(letter))
```

It is a bit more maintainable. Although, I have not found a way around the setting two separate frames.

The frame that is in the answer did not work for me on rotation.

Comment: This worked for me today. In my case I am only using the lanscape mode for large images so having two frames is a plus because I need to do different things with the page margins. Thanks!